# css divs aren't floating in alignment

Tags: html, css

Hi i have coded my news content of my wordpress blog, i made the content float right and the date and comments float left of the conten, now it is floating perfectly except for one thing.

The date and comments for the first post is aligned but the date and comments for the second post is also aligned with the first post, when it should be aligned with the second post. and the date and comments under the second post is suppose to be for the third post, which leaves the last post without date time or comments. Example below.

[image]

here is my css

```
  #content {
width: 1070px;
}
.right{
position:relative;
float:right;
right:215px;
}

.left{
position:relative;
float:left;
left:200px; 
display:block;
}

.date{
width:80px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
clear:left;
}

.month {
color:#fff;
font-size:15px;
font-family:eurofurence;
text-transform:uppercase;  
}

.year {
color:#fff;
padding:0 0 7px 0;
font-size:30px;
font-family:eurofurence;
text-transform:uppercase;  
}

.commentbubble{
  background: url('http://bleedartmedia.com/mock/wp-content/themes/KellyRowland/images/commentb.png') no-repeat;
  width:40px;
  height:49px;
  padding:4px 0 0 14px;
 }
    .entry {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
border-bottom: 0px solid #cccccc;
    font-family:eurofurence;
    font-size:17px;
    width:610px;
    background:#000;
}

    .entry-top {
margin: 0 0 0px 0;
padding: 0 0 0px 0;
text-align: left;

}

    .entry-top .entry-title {
color: #fff;
    font-family:eurofurence light;
    font-size:28px;
}

    .entry-top .entry-author {
font-style: italic;
}

    .entry-title {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: normal;
font-stretch: narrower;
}

    .entry-title a:link,
    .entry-title a:visited {
color: #fff;
    font-family:eurofurence light;
    font-size:28px;
}

    .entry-title a:hover {
color: #3E7AB9;
text-decoration: none;
}

    .entry-content {
margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px; 
    font-family:eurofurence;
    font-size:17px;
}
```

and here is my coding

```
      <div id="content">
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

  <div class="date left">
      <div class='month'><?php the_date('M');?></div>
      <div class='year'><?php the_time('d');?></div>

     <div class="commentbubble">
   <?php comments_popup_link( __( '0', 'wpbx' ), __( '1', 'wpbx' ), __( '%', 'wpbx' ) ) ?>
      </div>
      Comments
    </div>


            <div class="entry right">
    <div class="entry-top">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
    </div>
            <div class="entry-content clearfix">

        <div class="entry-content">
                <div id="text"><?php the_content() ?></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="entry-meta">

            </div>

    </div><!-- .post -->
      <br>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
```

Anyone have a solution

Comment: Take out the `<br>` and add some `margin-bottom` to `.entry`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your php while loop starts outside of the shown html? What I would do here is make sure that you contain your date-left and entry-right in a single div, and use the php while to repeat the div. I think all you'll have to do is find where your while loop starts, add a div, and then right before it ends add a closing div.

```
<loop start>
<div>
....(divs containing entry and date here)
</div>
<loop end>
```

Comment: No i don't think thats it the loop starts right before the "date left" div

Comment: I'm sorry, my solution seems to have been edited. I meant to advise you to add a div right after the while begins, that contains the date and entry, and then end the div right before the loop ends. That waythe dates can't be near each other, as the div will separate them.

Comment: Hi i did this, but it ended up as the first post date disappearing and the second post date being next to the first

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to clear the float:

```
.date.left { clear: left; }
```